# Angular.js set boolean scope variable when animation is occurring via UI-Router's ui-view directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I'm using the ui-router's ui-view directive and ng-animate 1.3.8 to add a CSS page transition when the ui-view content is updated on state change. I have the transition working perfectly but I would now like to define a boolean variable in the $rootScope that is set to `true` while the ui-view animation is occurring and `false` otherwise.

What is the Angular way of doing this? I've tried defining a new animation with a timeout set to the same time period as the css transition and then attaching it to the ui-view element but it only seems to work intermittently. It also seems completely bad practice so I'm keen to know the correct way. See code below:

In HTML:

```
<div ui-view="main" class="trans-timer"></div>
```

Animation:

```
.animation('.trans-timer', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done, memo) {
      $rootScope.isAnimating = true;
      $timeout(function () {
        $rootScope.isAnimating = false;
      }, 500);
     }
   };
})
```

Thanks.